# How do I format this so no spaces are made in python

Tags: python, string, format

For example,

```
def __str__(self):
    return "{} {} {} {}".format(self.title, self.year, self.rating, self.duration)

# Title                         Viewed      Rating      Duration (hours)
------------------------------------------------------------
1 ADA                             2050        3           1.5
2 B                             2020        4           4.5
3 C                             2040        5           2.5
```

I want the title, viewed, rating, and duration to be evened up and not have, for instance, title ADA to be pushing the year, rating, and duration to the right (or even not have them  be pushed away). How can I go about this?

Comment: I don't understand; where are the existing spaces come from? Anyway, did you try reading [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)?

Comment: Put field widths in the format.  For example, `"{:20} {:6} {:4} {:6}"

Comment: That solved it Tom appreciate it dude

Comment: @dasfoogle Glad it helped.  There is addition information you can specify as well (alignment, fractional width, etc.) - you can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

Comment: Oh wow this information is sick thanks again

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `escape characters` to format with tabs.

```py
def __str__(self):
  return "{}\t\t\t{}\t{}]\t{}".format(self.title, self.year, self.rating, self.duration)
```

If you google `escape characters` you can find a bunch of interesting things you can insert into strings.

Hope this helps/is what your looking for.

Comment: This is a bad solution that fails for widths that vary by 8 or more.  Using explicit field widths is the obvious solution.  It also places hard tabs in the output, which is undesirable.

Comment: It will even fail for width of, e.g., 7 and 9 - the resulting column will not align.